# protocol witness for Strideable.distance(to : A) -> A.Stride in conformance Int64 + 124 - what does this error message mean?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I have got a bunch of crash logs from iTunesConnect for my ios swift app with the top of the stacktrace showing the error message:

> protocol witness for Strideable.distance(to : A) -> A.Stride in conformance Int64 + 124

This comes from an innocuous line in my code which looks like the following:

```
if (var1 - var2 > MyClass.THRESHOLD) {
    // Do something
}
```

`var1` and `var2` are declared to be of type `Int64`, while `THRESHOLD` is:

```
static let THRESHOLD = 900 * 1000
```

I have a hunch that this is because `THRESHOLD` is not declared to be of `Int64`, though I still don't have a hypothesis as to how this could cause a problem. Also, the bug is not reproducible, so I can't verify.

Any help on what this error message means, and what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mixed-type comparison can be
the cause for the problem. The subtraction operator is inferred from
the types of its operands as

```
@available(swift, deprecated: 3.0, obsoleted: 4.0, message: "Mixed-type subtraction is deprecated. Please use explicit type conversion.")
public func -<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T.Stride where T : SignedInteger
```

with `T == Int64` and `T.Stride == Int`. Your code would cause a warning message with Xcode 8.3.2:

```
let THRESHOLD = 900 * 1000

let var1: Int64 = 0x100000000
let var2: Int64 = 0

// warning: '-' is deprecated: Mixed-type subtraction is deprecated. Please use explicit type conversion.
if var1 - var2 > THRESHOLD {
    print("foo")
} else {
    print("bar")
}
```

On a 32-bit device the difference can be too large for an `Int`
and the above example would abort with a runtime error

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0223d428 libswiftCore.dylib`protocol witness for Swift.Strideable.distance (to : A) -> A.Stride in conformance Swift.Int64 : Swift.Strideable in Swift + 72
```

The solution is to explicitly convert the right-hand side:

```
if var1 - var2 > Int64(THRESHOLD) { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry for the off top but Matrin do you have dev blog? I am curious about staff that you are working on.

Comment: Just cross-checked our logs, and all crashes have indeed come from 32 bit machines! It did not occur to me that the overflow would cause a crash there. Thanks!
  Just curious, what does '+72' signify in the message - 'protocol witness for Swift.Strideable.distance (to : A) -> A.Stride in conformance Swift.Int64 : Swift.Strideable in Swift + 72'?

Comment: @adarsh: That is 72 bytes (?) after the start of the function.